# pyqt5 QTextEdit Windows 10 ASCII symbols

Tags: python, windows, pyqt5, ascii, qtextedit

I use PyQt5 and QTextEdit widget. I want to get a plain text from file and show it in QTextEdit. This is what I have in a text file

[image]

This is how I initialize QTextEdit

```
self.info_text_edit.setPalette(palette)
font = QtGui.QFont()
font.setFamily("Courier")
font.setPointSize(10)
font.setStyleStrategy(QtGui.QFont.NoAntialias)
self.info_text_edit.setFont(font)
self.info_text_edit.setLineWrapMode(QtWidgets.QTextEdit.WidgetWidth)
self.info_text_edit.setReadOnly(True)
```

Then for append a text I just do

```
self.info_text_edit.append(str(msg))
```

With this approach on Linux - everything works well. But this is what I see as a result on Windows

[image]

Comment: What is missing is the exact text that you have written into this TextEdit. Isn't it just a case of using the wrong encoding – say, UTF-8? The [Solid Black Block U+2588](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2588/index.htm) encoded in UTF-8, is `0xE2 0x96 0x88` or `â–ˆ` (for my system; the actual 3-character display depends on your active Windows codepage).

Comment: @usr2564301 for this case - correct. But there might be any characters

Comment: And of course they will be mangled in the same way. But how and why, we cannot tell if you're not helping us help you.

Comment: @usr2564301 what I see in the first picture is correct. I wanna see the same in my QTextEdit

Comment: I got that. What's in `msg`, and why does it needs converting to `str` (if it's not already a string)? That seems to be the cause. That's what I want to know.

Comment: @usr2564301 ah yes. Im sorry. There is only string, directly from the file. Or you can assume that there is only string

Answer (score 0):

There was mistake in coding\decoding..

When I write `msg` to the file I should do following:

```
import platform
if platform.system() == "Linux":
    msg = str(msg)
elif platform.system() == "Windows":
    msg = str(msg).encode("utf-8").decode('cp1251')
```

Then when I read `msg` from file I should do this:

```
import platform
if platform.system() == "Linux":
    self.info_text_edit.append(str(msg))
elif platform.system() == "Windows":
    self.info_text_edit.append(str(msg).encode('cp1251').decode('utf-8'))
```